# How to create a weekly alert system that works for different sample sizes?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, sample-size, small-sample

I'm trying to build a weekly alert system to let me know when something unusual has happened in my analytics data that might require further investigation. Currently there is an outdated system in place that only looks at week over week % increase, which obviously is not working.

Let's think about the only metric as website hits (x). I have about 2,000 websites that show great difference in size from each other. We can categorize them under 2 behaviors.

1. Shows high activity with low variance (x~ 100,000)
2. Shows low activity with high variance (x~ 100)

I am trying to come up with an approach that is robust for all and minimize false positives. Need something smart enough to tell me that 10% increase in 100K is more important than 50% increase in 100.

- What do we have in literature for these kind of problems? What are they called?
- Is it better to categorize the websites based on their activity (average, std_dev) and create separate alert system?
- What would the best way be to deal with seasonality? (ie travel seasons which would skew averages and standard deviations)
- How should I deal with small websites? Would I have to take a longer time frame to calculate averages? How would I decide how many to take?

Comment: Is this question about customers or websites? I think the former.

Comment: Both, customers are the websites.